# Firebase Firestore returning empty array when using combined query

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I'm trying to combine two filters in the same firebase query.  when I tried to use only search query it perfectly working and also same as the date range query. but when I combined these two queries it returns an empty array. I don't understand why this happening. here is my combined query. what is wrong with it.

```
export const getUsers = async (minDate:Date, maxDate:Date) => {
   
admin
   .firestore()
   .collection("users")
   .where("name", ">=", "abc")
   .where('name', "<=", "abc"+"~")
   .orderBy('name', "asc")
   .orderBy('createdAt')
   .startAt(admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date(minDate)))
   .endAt(admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date(maxDate)))
   .get()
   .then(async (DS) => {
                if ( DS ) {
                    const arr: any[] = [];

                   await DS.docs.forEach(doc=>{
                        arr.push(doc.data())
                    })
                    functions.logger.info(
                        "get successfully - ",
                        await DS.docs
                    );
                    
                    return arr;
                } else {
                    
                    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
                        "invalid-argument",
                        ""
                    );
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
                    "invalid-argument",
                    error.message
                );
            });
}
```

I'm using firebase admin in cloud functions, and also all indexes are created which suggest by firebase.

Comment: is it possible that a document that meets all criteria does not exist?

Comment: actually, there is some document which match to those two criteria. I'm only adding 2021 dates in the createdAt field as  Timestamp and I have tried. 2020 date as minDate and 2022 date as the max date but it still returns an empty array.

Comment: What do you see if if you log the size of the QuezrySnapshot? `then(async (DS) => {functions.logger.info("size", DS.size); ...})`? Also, can you share the **entire** code of your Cloud Function?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec when I log size in console  display this message 

" {"severity":"INFO","message":"Size  0"} "

Comment: It means that you query returns zero doc. You have to understand why.

Comment: yes. that's what I'm trying to figure out. is that firestore not support multiple query’s or is it an async functional problem?.